# Adding new columns to Oracle Extracts and to populate data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an extract abc.txt, now I need to add two new columns and populate data in the extract

Table A:

```
NUM CODE PRODUCT ID
1         alpha 
1    ac          56
1    bb          44
1    dw          27
```

Join with another table
Table B:

```
NUM CODE
1    ac
1    bb
1    dw
```

The output in the extract should be as follows for two new columns PRODUCT and ID are new columns:

```
CODE NUM PRODUCT ID
ac    1   alpha  56
bb    1   alpha  44
dw    1   alpha  27
```

Comment: Seems to be a join between `TableA` and `TableB` on `NUM` and `CODE` or ?

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Here you will get answers to issues you face, however this is not a code writing service. Please read [ask] and follow that as a template for your question. In this case @Sujitmohanty30 seems to have the exact answer you require.

Answer (score 1):

You can join those tables along with a correlated subquery :

```
SELECT A.code,A.num,
       (SELECT MAX(product) FROM TableA) AS product,
       A.id
  FROM TableA A
  JOIN TableB B
    ON B.num = A.num AND B.code = A.code
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1795d89d818c81242e51c5b7d2b3de03)</kbd>